# How to recursively search directory in C++/CLI

Tags: windows, c++-cli, managed-c++

Googling for an windows example of a recursive search i found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307009) but trying to compile this with cl (and the MSVC++ tool chain) the compiler states error over error. Do I need to include some extra libraries directly as soon as i am not using the usual setup done by the MSVC++ GUI.

The posted example error codes are translated and therefore might not look exactly like they would in English.

```
"*": This referencing cannot be done for System::String the compiler substitutes "*" by 
"^" to continue analysis
```

and

```
System::String ^ a system-owned array cannot contain this managed type
```

both those errors are on this line

```
String* directories[] = Directory::GetDirectories(dir.c_str()); //dir is a usual string
```

and therefore are not my coding.

What am I messing up?

The compile-line was:

```
cl /w /c /clr file.cpp
```

Comment: That code is written in 'Managed Extensions for C++' syntax, but you're compiling as C++/CLI -- two different languages, of course it won't work.

Comment: @Fanael : The `c++` tag is entirely appropriate for this question, since the linked code is in fact _not_ C++/CLI.

Comment: @ildjarn: it is C++/CLI, just look at it, at the error messages, and at the compiler invocation. It's not really related to C++.

Comment: @ildjarn how do I do it the right way as I actually want to write C++? I am used to Linux and therefore struggle with this windows world nestings.

Comment: @Fanael : One line of code is enough to make it obvious -- `String* directories[] = Directory::GetDirectories("C:\\");` is not C++/CLI, it is Managed Extensions for C++. I.e., the problem is that the OP is trying to compile code that is not C++/CLI as C++/CLI.

Comment: @Sim : Why are you trying to use C++/CLI then? If you're used to C or C++ then stick with C or C++. Just because you're using Windows doesn't mean you have to target .NET

Comment: @ildjarn: that line is erroneous in C++/CLI and the compiler is complaining (and that's why the OP asked the question). Managed Extensions for C++ are unsupported by newer VS versions, I think that the chances of OP using an old version are quite small, if she did, she'd probably know what she's doing.

Comment: @Fanael : Read the article -- `The following list outlines the recommended hardware, software, network infrastructure, and service packs that you need: Microsoft Visual C++ .NET or Microsoft Visual C++ 2005` VC++ 2002, 2003, 2005, 2008, and 2010 **all** support Managed Extensions for C++, and 2002 and 2003 didn't have C++/CLI at all. Yes, that line is erroneous C++/CLI, but it is valid Managed Extensions for C++ -- **clearly** the code is Managed Extensions for C++, I don't know what further proof you could possibly want.

Comment: @iIldjarn well windows doesn't support dirent.h and I looked for an easy way to implement a directory search without falling back to any GNU dependencies and btw "she" is actually a "he".

Comment: @Sim : See [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/) if you want to stick with cross-platform C++.

Comment: @ildjarn: if it's Managed Extensions for C++, then *why the compiler complains*? Because it thinks it's C++/CLI. The article is written in one language, but the compiler wants a different one. Rather than arguing over that, we both could help the OP and translate it from MC++ to C++/CLI and everyone would be happy. Also, VC++ 2008 and 2010 don't support MC++ anymore. And also, even though it's MC++, it's still not C++, and that's what I meant from the beginning.

Comment: @ildjarn actually I don't need cross-platform just simple inside windows portability and no big second libraries as I want to easily move the code to another (windows)OS and just type in nmake to compile it.

Comment: @Fanael : As I've already said multiple times now, the compiler is complaining because the OP is attempting to compile Managed Extensions for C++ code as though it were C++/CLI. If you're going to get into a pointless argument, please at least read what's been said already. (And VC++ 2008 and 2010 **do** support Managed Extensions for C++ -- it's called `/clr:oldSyntax`, just like it was in 2005.)

Comment: @Sim: it was a "generic she", I didn't know the gender so I defaulted to "she", whereas other people would probably use "they" instead.

Comment: @ildjarn: in short, you were saying that the compiler is complaining because the OP is trying to compile **MC++** as C++/CLI, and I was saying that compiler is complaining because the OP is trying to compile MC++ as **C++/CLI**. Maybe I was led astray by the title. But that's not what I wanted to say, my point in deleting that tag was that **it's not C++**, it's MC++, or C++/CLI, or something else that is based on C++ but has numerous extensions to allow writing .NET code (I know, I don't tell these apart, my bad). Do we have to argue, or can we get over it?

Comment: @Fanael : The only reason I said anything in the first place was to make it clear that the `c++` tag is appropriate because the code is not C++/CLI. If that's understood then we're over it. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: There's a tag for Managed Extensions for C++, and the code is not standard C++, not even a vendor specific flavor of C++.  It's a different language.  And VC++2005 and above don't support MC++, they support the syntax of MC++ using `/clr:oldSyntax` but the semantics have changed rather significantly.

Comment: @Ben : I wasn't aware of the `managed-c++` tag, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Directory::GetDeirectories is a .net call so it will return a .net object. You are trying to cast it to a c++ pointer. Your best bet is to declare a .net string array instead. The type is like so

```
array<String^>^ directories = Directory::GetDirectories(dir.c_str());
```

Comment: I would actually love to somehow follow that supplied guide by microsoft and not getting stuck in another language.

Comment: Well I'm a little confused. If you are using CLI c++ then the above answer is correct. However if you are looking for cross compatibility you should probably look at a native function of c++

Comment: Well my goal was (like stated in the comments above) to write a small windows compatible code to go through folders and look for a certain file type. I didn't mean to use any of this stuff, just got that as a hit in google tried it and got really confused by the compiler and thought i missed a compile option.